# Python regular expressions two character contain

Tags: python, expression

How can I write regular expression for a string in python, which contains two characters min. 1x time.

For example I am looking for characters `6` and `=`:

String1: `Test 6 =` is correct.
String2: `6 test =` is correct.
String3: `=6` is correct.
String4: `Test 5 - 8` is incorrect.
String5: `Test 6` is incorrect.
String6: `Test =` is incorrect.

I tried `[6+=+]` but is not working correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: Can You edit your explanation and example to make it more clear? Are u looking for a string that contains two characters from `6, +, =`? Maybe give more examples and explain why are they good or bad.

Comment: Is `re` expression really necessary in your case?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **positive lookahead** might be your solution here.

Tested and working:

```
(?=.*[6])(?=.*[=]).*
```

I've tried it at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#python), which you might also find helpful while testing your regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for two characters anywhere in the string. You may not need an re.

```
for item in ['6', '=']:
   found = string_to_search.count(item)
   # item must be present
   if not found:
      # handle bad data
   # make sure there is only one match
   if found > 1:
      # handle bad data
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using regular expressions is slower then using string operations. I think You can solve Your issue more effectively using something like this:

```
>>> a
'test 6 ='
>>> [idx for idx, ch in enumerate(a) if ch == '6' or ch == '=']
[5, 7]
```